# Ordering recursive function results in arrays of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I am currently dealing with in issue in writing a recrusive function to order some json data. I have several nested arrays of objects which i need to order into single slides. The structure is similar to the following :

```
[
{
    "title": "a",
    "children": [
        {
            "title": "a-a",
            "children": [
                {
                    "title": "a-a-a"
                },
                {
                    "title": "a-a-b"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "a-b",
            "children": [
                {
                    "title": "a-b-a"
                },
                {
                    "title": "a-b-b"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "title": "b",
    "children": [
        {
            "title": "b-a",
            "children": [
                {
                    "title": "b-a-a"
                },
                {
                    "title": "b-a-b"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title": "b-b",
            "children": [
                {
                    "title": "b-b-a"
                },
                {
                    "title": "b-b-b"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
]
```

I have written a recursive function :

```
var catalog = {

init: function() {

    var _this = this;

    $.getJSON("catalog.json", function(data) {

        _this.slides = [];
        _this.parseCategories(data.catalog.category,-1,0);

    });

},

parseCategories: function(array, depth, prevParent) {
    ++depth;

    if (!this.slides[depth]) this.slides[depth] = [];
    if (!this.slides[depth][prevParent]) this.slides[depth][prevParent] = [];

    this.slides[depth][prevParent].push(array);

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

        if (array[i].category) {

            this.parseCategories(array[i].category, depth, i);
        }
    }

}

}

catalog.init();
```

This outputs :

[image]

However instead of retrieving the data for my third slide under format :

a-a-a

a-b-a

a-c-a

I would like to get

a-a-[a,b,c]

I was wondering if that was possible since I'm not very good at handling recursive processes. I hope I was clear and thank you for reading this.
I basically need to keep my original data structure but remove the first depth level for each iteration (slide in a slider that represent increasing depths in my data structure).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your exact problem. I solved a similar problem recently though, and perhaps [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31461290/361762) will help you. If not please see if you can clarify the problem--the images of the expected output at the top are useful and something like that with your actual results would help explain.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately I believe my problem might be slightly more complicated.I have edited my post with a new image that confronts the output my function returns and the output I actually need. The idea is that i need to then build a slider through a handlebars template and navigate between children and parents while hiding all unnecessary data. Therefore my output must return the data under the form of an array per depth and structure each subcategory in an array while the depth increases. I could use several loops but I'm afraid of the performance costs.

Comment: Could you provide your real json structure? Your current json doesn't match with the example in the image. If possible a jsfiddle with what you've done

Comment: same request as @FabioLuz

Comment: please supply a wanted order for the given object

Comment: What you try is recursively not possible (unless you make some weird if statements to check the depth, but than what is the point to do it recursive). Why it is not possible is because you want to change the structure of the output on depth 1, after it is already processed. Your last image can only be generated if you have knowledge of the last depth before you create the last-1 depth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently wrote a algorithm to recursively handle data like this. Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dc9stqo9/1/) and the main function

```
console.log('starting');
// data in tree format.
var output = {};
// data in slide format ["a-a-a", "a-a-b", "b-b-a", "b-b-b"]
var outputStrs = [];
parseData(data, output);
console.log(output);
console.log(outputStrs);

function parseData(data, store) {
    // go through each element 
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var element = data[i];
        // used to keep track of where we are in the tree.
        var splitElement = element.title.split('-'); 
        var titleStart = splitElement[0];
        // console.log(element);
        if (_.has(element, 'children') && _.isArray(element.children)) {
            // if there is a children, then recursively handle it. 
            store[titleStart] = {};
            parseData(element.children, store[titleStart]);
        } else {
            // if we are at the end, then add in the data differently. 
            var titleEnd = splitElement[splitElement.length-1];
            store[titleEnd] = titleEnd;
            // create the slides 
            var slide = [];
            for (var j = 0; j < splitElement.length; j++) {
                if (j !== splitElement.length - 1) {
                    slide.push(titleStart); 
                } else {
                    slide.push(titleEnd); 
                }
            }
            slide = slide.join('-');
            if (!_.contains(outputStrs, slide)) outputStrs.push(slide);
        }
    }
}
```

With this data the output should resemble

```
a
    a
        a
        b
b
    b
        a
        b
```

And outputStrs will resemble a-a-[a,b,c]

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Thank you very much, I had actually simplified the whole system to fit my needs ( adding a marker in the dom instead of trying to format the array perfectly) but this might fit my previous need.